# Determine what caused an observable to complete

Tags: rxjs

I have the following basic Observable setup:

```
fooObservable
  .pipe(takeUntil(barObservable))
  .subscribe({
    complete: () => {
      // Do something only if fooObservable completes, not if barObservable emits.
    }
  })
```

As you can see in the comment above, I want to "do something" in the completion block only if the observable is completed due to `fooObservable` completing. If it completes due to `barObservable` emitting, I do not want to do anything. How can I determine what caused this observable to complete to write this logic?

Comment: If you care which source observable completed, maybe you need a combining operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a way to address your question using the `tap` operator just before the `takeUntil` operator and passing into the `complete` function of the `tap` operator the logic you want to run when `foo` completes.

This is the code and this is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-7c6wg6)

```
const foo = of('foo').pipe(
  delay(200)
)

const bar = of('bar').pipe(
  delay(300)
)
foo
.pipe(
  tap({
    complete: () => console.log('DONE because FOO completed')
  }),
  takeUntil(bar)
)
.subscribe({
  complete: () => console.log('don not do anything since you are here because BAR emitted')
})
```

If your requisite requires strictly that you run the code you want to run in the `complete` function passed to the `subscribe` method, then you can do something similar but you would be required to use some variable to store the state. Such variable should be set withing the `complete` function of the `tap` operator

Answer (score 1):

The first idea I got:

```
let barEmitted = false;

fooObservable
  .pipe(takeUntil(barObservable.pipe(tap(() => barEmitted = true))))
  .subscribe({
    complete: () => {
      if(!barEmitted) { do your stuff}
    } 
  })
```

a bit hacky, but I've never encountered your situation before :)

Answer (score 0):

If `fooObservable` terminates because of `barObservable` and you want to execute some logic when `barObservable` emits the first value you can move this logic to `barObservable` :

```js
barObservable
 .pipe(take(1))
 .subscribe(e => /*Do something only if barObservable completes*/)
```

```js
fooObservable
  .pipe(takeUntil(barObservable))
  .subscribe({
    complete: () => {
      // continue to do nothing
    }
  })
```